# Why my group is with another country subdomain in search results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

My family has a group. We are from Ukraine. Group has a native name "Квіти з Нідерландів".
https://www.facebook.com/groups/merryflowers
When I tried to search our group name on google I have got weird results:

[image]

ar-ar.facebook.com › groups › merryflowers
‏‎Квіти з Нідерландів‎‏ - مجموعة عامة | فيسبوك

It some Arabic subdomain.
Why it can be? Is it bad SEO of Facebook or something wrong in google algorithms. Or maybe we did some bad configuration of our group?

Comment: _“Why it can be?”_ - because Facebook made it available under that subdomain. Nothing more to say about this here, really - this is not an actual programming question of the type you should ask here to begin with.

Comment: _“Is it bad CEO of Facebook”_ - there’s probably plenty of people, who consider the CEO of Facebook to be a bad guy, for multiple reasons, yes. (But you probably didn’t mean the actual job or the person, but _SEO_ …)

Comment: @misorude Thank you.